# What could cause "This item is no longer reviewable." in the reopen review queue?

Tags: support, review, reopened-questions

I'm just curious. Case in point : [review item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/1396395), [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14532105/revisions).

In this case, revision history is showing that the question was reopened by v,w,x,y,z. But the review queue item is showing not reviewable, whereas it should show "Review completed".

What happened here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was probably reopened with a straight reopen vote from the question, not through the review queue.  You can see that the last reopener isn't in the review list.

Comment: oh of course...